# Error al colocar datos en una tabla

Tags: mysql-workbench

Porque al intentar colocar datos en la tabla "alumnos" me da error, el ejemplo que puse fue poner un nombre y edad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Jorge, acostumbra agregar el código como texto, es más legible para la comunidad, revisa [ask]. Aprovecho para invitarte a leer el [tour] del sitio que describe el funcionamiento básico del mismo, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Cambia ese tipo de comillas por `''` y no se deben poner en el tipo de dato int solo deja el numero, entonces quedaria asi:

```
INSERT INTO alumnos (nombre,edad) VALUES ('jose',22);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Debes indicar el nombre de los campos dónde vas a insertar los valores. A su vez la edad es un valor int y debe ir sin comillas.
Prueba así:

```
Insert into alumnos (nombre, edad) values ('jose', 22);
```

Comment: Gracias, lo logré

Comment: @JorgeGuadalupeGomezPimentel entonces [acepta la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Primeramente las comillas usadas como contenedor para indicar cadenas de carácter son:

`"` (ejemplo: `"JOSE"`) o también `'` (ejemplo: `'JOSE'`).

no se debe usar  `´` como en el caso de tu query ya que esto provoca que la cadena sea interpretada como columna (`no such column: ´JOSE´` ) la cual no existe.

---

El campo `nombre` es de tipo `varchar` y el campo edad es de tipo `int` por lo tanto este no debe tener comillas:

```
INSERT INTO alumnos VALUES ('JOSE', 22);
```

---

Veo que otras publicaciones indican que debes definir los campos, en realidad esto no es necesario en este caso ya que vas a insertar valores en todos los campos de la tabla.

```
INSERT INTO alumnos (nombre, edad) VALUES ('JOSE', 22);
```

Si fueras a insertar solo en algún o algunos campos de la tabla en ese caso si debes definir los campos de la tabla los cuales serán modificados.

```
INSERT INTO alumnos (edad) VALUES (22);
```

Answer (score 2):

Existen formas para hacerlo, yo en mi caso lo he logrado empleando algo como esto:

```
Insert Into alumno (nombre, edad) values ('{0}', '{1}'),jose, 22
```

o tambien podrias hacerlo de manera directa

```
Insert into nameTable (campo1, campo2) values (Dato1, Dato2);
```

en la estructura de tu tabla tienes algo muy particular y es que has declaro tu primer campo como string para esto tendras que enviar tu dato con comillas `''` para que lo reconozca como string, quedaria algo como esto:

```
Insert into nameTable (campo1, campo2) values ('Dato1', Dato2);
```

para los datos tipo enteros, decimales, numericos, etc.. no es necesario emplear las comillas.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias

Answer (score 1):

No has indicado en que filas de la tabla alumnos vas a ingresar los valores de jose, 22.

Prueba lo siguiente

```
INSERT INTO alumnos (nombre,edad) VALUES ("jose","22");
```